# How to sort files in folders according to their names

Tags: powershell

Hello it is my first time with Powershell and I would like to sort my files (example name: 5035 facture coop.pdf) according to the 4 first digits in their names and move them in other folders (example names: 5100 subvention, 5150 dons, 5200 dépenses courantes, etc)

The folders need to contain the files lesser or equal to the number in their name but higher than the one of the folder below them.

example: 5035 facture X.pdf would go in the folder 5100 subvention
but 5101 Facture y.pdf would go in the folder 5150 dons

I tried to assemble some code from other place in the forum and other forum as well, but I failed, miserably

## Folder where Files are located

```
$TopFolder = "C:\Users\Administration\Desktop\scannes"
```

## Folder where the destination folders are located

```
$destination = "C:\Users\Administration\Desktop\comptabilité essai"
```

## Getting Files

```
$Folders = gci $TopFolder -OutVariable Files | ? { $_.PSisContainer }
```

## Loop over all Files with *.docx extension

```
$Files | ? { $_.Extension -eq '.docx' } | % {

    # Split FileName to get the number
    $num = ($_.Name -split " ")[0]

    # Get FolderName and compare it to number
    $MoveTo = $destination | ? { $_.Name.substring(0,4) -ge $num }

    # If a folder was found, move file there. else print error
    if ($MoveTo)
    {
        Move-Item $_.FullName $MoveTo 
        Write-Host "Copied File $($_.Name) to $MoveTo"
    }
    else 
    { 
        Write-Host "Did not find folder $($num) in $TopFolder" 
    }
}
```

I don't know how to make the rule for lesser or equal but greater than other folder, And it doesn't work at all.

Comment: `$destination` is just a string so when you pipe it to `?` (`Where-Object`), it won't return anything because it doesn't have a property called `$_.Name` , didn't you mean to set it to an array, like: `$destination = gci "C:\Users\Administration\Desktop\comptabilité essai"`?

Comment: Additionally, saying `? { $_.Name.substring(0,4) -ge $num }` may return more than one folder, so you need to pick the first folder that has a name greater than or equal to `$num`

Comment: @mjsqu Thanks! It is my first real code, having only a little experience in VBA Excel.  I'm adding it right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on mjsqu's comments, if you set your `$destination` variable to .

```
$destination = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Administration\Desktop\comptabilité essai" -Directory
```

and modify your `$MoveTo = ...` line to be

```
$MoveTo = $destination | ? { $_.Name.substring(0,4) -ge $num } | Sort-Object -Property Name | Select-Object -First 1
```

that will make `$MoveTo` contain the first folder with name greater than the number.

Then you might need to modify your `Move-Item $_.FullName $MoveTo` line to say `Move-Item $_.FullName $MoveTo.FullName` to get the directory name.

Comment: @Neeser Glad to help!